# MinGW32: Linking against ImageMagick with -static flag

Tags: linker, imagemagick, mingw, static-libraries, building

I am currently trying to build a Windows-version of emacs that supports ImageMagick.

For that purpose I have already compiled ImageMagick with MinGW32/MSys in order to get compatible library files. Basically linking also works, though I have to add explicitly `-llibMagickCore-6.Q16` and `-llibMagickWand-6.Q16` to the linking command through `configure.bat`'s `--lib` option.

However, the binary distribution of emacs for windows is supposed to load, even when the dependencies are absent. This behaviour I obtain when I add the linker option (`configure.bat --ldflags`) `-static`.

However, when I try to compile with ImageMagick-Support, static linking fails saying it cannot find the ImageMagick includes.

The library files are located in `D:/BUILD/libraries/lib`. As a minimal example:

```
D:\>ld -LD:/BUILD/libraries/lib -llibMagickWand-6.Q16

D:\>ld -static -LD:/BUILD/libraries/lib -llibMagickWand-6.Q16
ld: cannot find -llibMagickWand-6.Q16
```

The directory does however contain the static library.

```
D:\BUILD\libraries\lib>dir *Magick*
[...]
2013-07-02  15:16         2,585,830 libMagick++-6.Q16.a
2013-07-02  15:16         1,745,404 libMagick++-6.Q16.dll.a
2013-07-02  15:16             1,178 libMagick++-6.Q16.la
2013-07-02  15:16         5,153,712 libMagickCore-6.Q16.a
2013-07-02  15:16           977,292 libMagickCore-6.Q16.dll.a
2013-07-02  15:16             1,096 libMagickCore-6.Q16.la
2013-07-02  15:16         1,609,692 libMagickWand-6.Q16.a
2013-07-02  15:16           472,364 libMagickWand-6.Q16.dll.a
2013-07-02  15:16             1,142 libMagickWand-6.Q16.la
```

Any idea, what could be going wrong here? From what I understand, the `.a` files are the static libraries for MinGW, so the absence of `.lib` files (Visual Studio) shouldn't be a problem.

I have used the Unix source distribution of ImageMagick, because the Windows sources require Visual Studio for building.

Answer (score 1):

I found the error looking at `ld -verbose=0 ...`.

For some reason, when using the `-static` flag the lookupbehaviour changes. Without the `-static` flag:

```
...
attempt to open D:/BUILD/libraries/lib/liblibMagickWand-6.Q16.dll.a failed
attempt to open D:/BUILD/libraries/lib/libMagickWand-6.Q16.dll.a succeeded
```

with `-static` flag:

```
...
attempt to open D:/BUILD/libraries/lib\liblibMagickWand-6.Q16.a failed
attempt to open c:\mingw\bin\../../MinGW/usr/local/lib\liblibMagickWand-6.Q16.a failed
attempt to open c:\mingw\bin\../../MinGW/lib\liblibMagickWand-6.Q16.a failed
attempt to open c:\mingw\bin\../../MinGW/usr/lib\liblibMagickWand-6.Q16.a failed
attempt to open D:/BUILD/libraries/lib\libMagickWand-6.Q16.lib failed
attempt to open c:\mingw\bin\../../MinGW/usr/local/lib\libMagickWand-6.Q16.lib failed
attempt to open c:\mingw\bin\../../MinGW/lib\libMagickWand-6.Q16.lib failed
attempt to open c:\mingw\bin\../../MinGW/usr/lib\libMagickWand-6.Q16.lib failed
ld: cannot find -llibMagickWand-6.Q16
```

Writing `-lMagickWand-6.Q16` instead of `-llibMagickWand-6.Q16` worked.