# Undefined reference Magick++ to Qt project on Windows

Tags: c++, windows, qt, dll, linker-errors

I have a problem linking Magick++ to Qt project on Windows x32 machine.
On linux it works just fine(I got source files and used make and make install)

Here's .pro file code for

```
unix {
    LIBS += -L/usr/local/lib \
    -lMagick++-6.Q16 -lMagickWand-6.Q16 -lMagickCore-6.Q16
}
```

Here goes method for converting pdf to image using magick++:

```
#include <Magick++.h>
#include <QImage>
#include <QDebug>
using namespace std;

QImage pdfToImage(const QString &pathToFile, const QString &targetImageType)
{
   try
   {
       Magick::Image img;
       Magick::Blob blob;
       img.read(pathToFile.toStdString());

       img.magick(targetImageType.toStdString());
       img.write(&blob);
       const QByteArray imageData((char*)(blob.data()),blob.length());
       QImage image;
       image.loadFromData(imageData);
       return image;
   }
  catch (Magick::Warning &warning)
  {
      qDebug() << warning.what();
     return QImage();
 }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   pdfToImage("filename", "png");
   return 0;
}
```

Here goes my .pro file:

```
QT += core widgets

TARGET = magickcpp_test_include
TEMPLATE = app

SOURCES += main.cpp

win32: LIBS += -L$$PWD/libs/ImageMagick-6.8.5/win32/ -llibMagick++-6.Q16.dll

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/libs/ImageMagick-6.8.5/include/ImageMagick-6
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/libs/ImageMagick-6.8.5/win32


win32: LIBS += -L$$PWD/libs/ImageMagick-6.8.5/win32/ -llibMagickCore-6.Q16.dll

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/libs/ImageMagick-6.8.5/include/ImageMagick-6
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/libs/ImageMagick-6.8.5/win32

win32: LIBS += -L$$PWD/libs/ImageMagick-6.8.5/win32/ -llibMagickWand-6.Q16.dll

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/libs/ImageMagick-6.8.5/include/ImageMagick-6
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/libs/ImageMagick-6.8.5/win32
```

Output:

```
C:\Users\vadixem\qt_projects\magickpp_test_include\main.cpp:13: error: undefined reference to `Magick::Image::read(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)'
C:\Users\vadixem\qt_projects\magickpp_test_include\main.cpp:15: error: undefined reference to `Magick::Image::magick(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)'
collect2.exe:-1: error: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I was looking for answer for a very long time. Please help. Thanks in advance

Comment: -llibMagickWand-6.Q16.dll  This is not lib))

Comment: @Programmer_ARM  Well, at least that's what "Add library..." option on right click on project and then selecting "External library" allows me to do... And the full name is  libMagickWand-6.Q16.dll.a

Comment: Writing -lMagickWand-6.Q16 instead of -llibMagickWand-6.Q16 .

Comment: Use the same `-l...`s as for Linux. Btw, no need to add the other elements more than once.

Comment: @O'Neil This doesn't work as well. And there's no difference in  outcome whether you duplicate includes and depends or not.

Comment: @Programmer_ARM doesn't make any difference

Comment: [MinGW32: Linking against ImageMagick with -static flag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17434022/mingw32-linking-against-imagemagick-with-static-flag)